# How to use jQuery to select two out of three inputs but not submit, reset, button or hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have three drop down in my form and I want two of them to keep the selected value on form submit.
Currently I am resetting the entire form by using ...

```
function resetForm(){
        $(':input','#formId').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden' ).val('').removeAttr('selected');
}
```

The drop down in my form are as follows -

```
<select class="dropDown" id="user"></select>
<select class="dropDown" name="service" id="service">
    <option value=''>---Please Select---</option>
    <option value='S84'>Stock Control</option>
</select>   
<select class="dropDown" id="process"></select>
```

Comment: which 2 has to keep the value

Comment: What drop down don't you want to keep selected?

Comment: the drop down with id "user" and "service" keeps selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to reset only 1 of the 3 select elements.

So add them to the not selector like

```
$(':input','#formId').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden, #user, #service' )
```

will not reset `user` and `service` select elements

Answer (score 0):

You've got almost the solution. There are plenty ways of restricting a set of element.

I Like filter because is self-descripting, and you can provide a custom function to customize the behaviour

Try something like this:

```
function resetForm(ignored) {
  // only select, textarea and input can have value inside a form. Immediately ignore hidden ones
  $('#formId textarea, input:not([hidden]), #formId select').filter(function() {
    // allows you to dynamically choose the ignored id. Or you can hard-code them.
    return ignored.indexOf($(this).attr('id')) === -1
  }).val('').removeAttr('selected');
}

resetForm(['process', 'user'])
```

Look at this [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6M49/)